# Изображение Background располагается не правильно

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

помогите пожалуйста: при дальнейшем уменьшении маштаба, данное изображения также начинает уменьшаться непропорционально экрану, что делать?
(Весь код по изображению на нижней части скрина)
[image: Нормальное изображение]

[image: Неправильное масштабирование]

Comment: Попробуйте width: 100%; и оберните в div.

Comment: Попробуйте media-query для определения минимального размера окна (когда уже начинает ехать фотка) и подставьте background-size: contain; или auto вместо сover, в зависимости от того как именно Вам нужно.